# How to import external .json file to Django database(sqlite)?

Tags: json, django, import

So, what is the basic thing I can do to initialize my Django database with the data I have in external .json file.

I tried to upload through admin's page after running `python manage.py runserver` but there is no import options.

Answer (score 0):

Why you would use a JSON file if you can to add a key in the database dictionary in the settings file?
For the case to use a json file,

```
config = open('./config.json',)
data = json.load(config)
```

Now use the data variable in the settings database dictionary

```
 DATABASES = {
     "default": data 
 }
```